# What's the best and cheapest way to deploy a web-app made by spring-boot and angular online?

Tags: spring-boot, deployment, cloud, angular8

I made this project composed by a back-end API in spring-boot and a front-end in Angular8.

---

I was wondering if I should find some cloud solution? I still haven't got the picture. Can someone help?
TANKS A LOT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may not be the best and cheapest way, but you can find the most suitable way that match your need.

1. If you happened to have a computer or workstation that can be turn on all the time and you also have a public IP Address, you can just deploy on it.
2. Or you can deploy it on Cloud Platform like AWS, GCP, Azure. You can choose the runtime environment and libraries you want so as to deploy your web-app.

You should also buy the domain name that point to your IP Address and get the certificate later to secure it using https.

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific cheaper way to do it. You can try AWS, Azure, GCP, Pivotal etc., depending on your use case of availablity and scalability. You can also try https://www.heroku.com/ to deploy and try out things.